# template return with d-pointer

Tags: c++, qt, templates

Having a template method that casts to a particular Class is sometimes userfull, and I do use quite a lot, but while Implementing the 'd-pointer', they stopped working, because I don't know the internals of the 'd' while in the header file. is there any way for the snipped bellow to work?

```
    class BlahPrivate;
    class Blah{
    public:
        template<typename T> T*method(){ return static_cast<T*>( d->object ); }
    private:

        BlahPrivate *d;
    }
```

Comment: Is `d-pointer` a term ? What problem are you facing ?

Comment: What is `BlahPrivate`?  It's not a template parameter, so you'll need to have its definition before you can dereference it (to e.g. access its members).

Comment: if you can't specify the BlahPrivate header file in Blah's header file, please include like this in the .cpp file
#include <blahprivate.h>
#include <blah.h>

Comment: You can add GetDObject(); in Blah and in cpp add Blah::GetDObject() { return d->object; }. And use GetDObject() in method().

Comment: @iammilind, 'd-pointer' is a term for a implementation of a OpaquePointer technique.

Comment: @Unni it's already in the cpp file.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth , I know, but I want to hide the implementations, that's why I use a d-pointer. so I cant have the definitions before I deference.

Comment: what type of return value for GetDObject(); have you used? void* ?

Comment: Where is the answer, I don't see any posts by 'luskan'.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you want to separate the cast logic from the template internals, you can do that with a PIMPL (Pointer to Impl) idiom, adding a layer of indirection.  Basically, place this template in its own header that DOES include the definition for BlahPrivate.  Make that standalone.  Then make a .h file that calls the function you have above, except it forwards the function call to the header file that has the BlahPrivate definition and cast logic.

Secondly, you're probably better off just defining implicit conversion operators in BlahPrivate for the types you'd like to convert it to... for example, putting this in your class:

```
operator std::string() { return std::string("This is a BlahPRivate"); }
```

would allow you to use BlahPrivate wherever a string was expected - it's pretty nifty :)  Obviously, you'd want to give your casts more meaning though.

Don't go crazy with the implicit cast operators or it will bite you in the butt.  Actually, I think this whole thing is probably a bad idea, because even your proposed function would make debugging hard - instead of getting a static cast error for a bad type on your line with the error, you'll get it in this function and have to trace it back.

Similarly, implicit casts may do a cast (and work) when you don't want them to: i.e. you wrote your parameters backwards in a function, and the std::string one was automatically converted to by the implicit function above - implicit casts lessen your type safety.  **Sometimes doing things by hand (when they're trivial like a cast) is better - after all, you really shouldn't have to cast often - if you do it's often a sign of bad design and you should rethink what you're doing.**

Comment: What I'm doing is an application that has multiple 'cores', and they are plugins, and the cores also load plugins, so it's a multi-plugin that load plugins system, with lots of casts.  luskan answer ( as a comment, on my post ) worked like a charm.